# Problem sending SMS text with a single quote character - mmcli (ModemManager)

Tags: quoting

This is an example from the `mmcli` manpage:

```
mmcli -m 0 --messaging-create-sms="text='Hello world',number='+1234567890'"
```

The details how it is parsed are unclear, the description says only `--messaging-create-sms=['KEY1=VALUE1,...']` and lists known keys. The value for the `text` key is an UTF-8 message text.

So this is the corresponding line from my script:

```
mmcli -m $modem --messaging-create-sms="text='$msg',number='$num'"
```

The probem is that the message must not contain a single quote. The error is:

> 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Message.InvalidPduParameter: Failed to convert message text to GSM'

Currently I'm replacing it by a double qoute. I tried backslash escaping, but it did not work. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the code doing the parsing is [here](https://github.com/openshine/ModemManager/blob/master/libmm-glib/mm-common-helpers.c#L514):

```c
/* Expecting input as:
 *   key1=string,key2=true,key3=false...
 * Strings may also be passed enclosed between double or single quotes, like:
 *   key1="this is a string", key2='and so is this' */
gboolean mm_common_parse_key_value_string(...)
```

So, providing you don't have both double and single quotes in your text you can use the opposite quote in the argument, for example:

```bash
case "$msg" in
*\'*\"*|*\"*\'*) echo oops; exit 1 ;;
*\'*)   q=\" ;;
*\"*)   q=\' ;;
esac

... --messaging-create-sms="text=$q$msg$q,number='$num'"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but I recently ran into the same problem. I needed support for messages that can contain both single and double quotes, which is not possible with the current string parsing.
I figured I'd fix it myself and forked the repository [here](https://github.com/tomwimmenhove/ModemManager) and added a command line option, `--messaging-create-sms-with-text`, that allows you to read the message text from a file (which could be stdin). The option works similar to `--messaging-create-sms-with-data`.

I've done a pull request, but the project seems not to be very active (last commit was Nov 4, 2021). We'll see.

EDIT: The project was hosted on [FreeDesktop's own gitlab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager). I just assumed it was on GitHub. My bad :)

[My changes](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager/-/commit/bd5a82845a653bd51707e08af44c787f737f9c8c) have since been accepted.